# Equation with three variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these two equations 
$$x+y+z=65.52 \hspace{10mm} x \, y \, z=65.52$$

I don't have a clue how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: I suspect that your two equations are $x+y+z=65.52$ and $xyz=65.52$, if so you might put the equations on separate lines so they do not run together.  You might also show some attempts to solve it.

Comment: Well, I have been asked to find three numbers whose sum and multiplication both equal to 65.52 n that's how I summarize the question. My attempts were, 
x + y + z = xyz 
=> (1/xy) + (1/yz) + (1/ zx) = 1 , but it took me nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

Does

$$
\frac {x+y+z}{xyz} = \frac {1}{yz} + \frac {1}{xz} + \frac {1}{xy} = 1
$$

help?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a quadratic equation $x((65.52-t)-x)=65.52/t$ where $t=z$ is a paremeter.